# prolog on netbeans plugin

Tags: prolog, netbeans-7, swi-prolog, netbeans-plugins

I have downloaded this [Prolog plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39471) for netbeans, and added successfully to the netbeans plugins.
in the prolog options i set the **Compiler Name** : `C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\swipl.exe`
and the **Compiler Arguments** as default : `-c` 
then i made a prolog project & prolog file and tested it, i got this in the **Output-Prolog**

```
Output of running C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\swipl.exe -c C:\Users\Tareq\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Prolog_project1\src\sieve.pro  is:

% C:\Users\Tareq\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Prolog_project1\src\sieve.pro compiled 0.00 sec, 9 clauses
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:must_be/2 from c:/program files/swipl/library/error
% autoloading oset:reverse/2 from c:/program files/swipl/library/lists
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:portray_clause/1 from c:/program files/swipl/library/listing
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:clause_info/4 from c:/program files/swipl/library/prolog_clause
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:initialization_layout/4 from c:/program files/swipl/library/prolog_clause
% autoloading qsave:current_foreign_library/2 from c:/program files/swipl/library/shlib
% autoloading prolog_debug:backtrace/1 from c:/program files/swipl/library/prolog_stack
% autoloading error:assertion/1 from c:/program files/swipl/library/debug
% autoloading record:member/2 from c:/program files/swipl/library/lists
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:clause_name/2 from c:/program files/swipl/library/prolog_clause
% Autoloader: iteration 1 resolved 10 predicates and loaded 10 files in 0.047 seconds.  Restarting ...
% autoloading prolog_source:directory_file_path/3 from c:/program files/swipl/library/filesex
% autoloading files_ex:use_foreign_library/2 from c:/program files/swipl/library/shlib
% autoloading files_ex:maplist/2 from c:/program files/swipl/library/apply
% autoloading files_ex:permission_error/3 from c:/program files/swipl/library/error
% Autoloader: iteration 2 resolved 1 predicates and loaded 4 files in 0.031 seconds.  Restarting ...
% Autoloader: loaded 11 files in 3 iterations in 0.125 seconds
```

I tried to add the library from **Tools > Ant Libraries > New Library > named it Prolog**
then in the **classpath** tab **Add JAR/Folder...**, then I added the library :
**C:\Program Files\swipl\lib.JAR**

I'm not sure that what I did is enough, but I can't find any tutorial for this, can you help me ?

Comment: Have you tried executing your Prolog code outside of Netbeans? Was the result different?

Comment: it's only one fact: `son(smeth,jack).`

Comment: OK. I don't know Prolog anyway, just curious.